# Understanding nested process substitution in bash, with a little awk

Tags: bash, awk, output-redirect, process-substitution

I can't seem to figure out, what happens here. I have 4 versions of the same code, the only difference is the order of the code-blocks/lines. My initial expectation was that the redirection order does not make any difference, but it does not seem to be correct. I have also assumed that the >() has some shielding properties from file-descriptor machinations, but no...

Please don't ask what am I using it for, nor do I need alternative solutions, I want to understand THIS piece of code. Or my belief in my understanding of process substitution will be broken forever...

**Metacode:**

```
1_cmd_producing_both_stdout_and_stderr
|
+-stdout-> 2_cmd_producing_both_stdout_and_stderr
|          |
|          +-stdout-> A_awk_writing_stdout_to_file_producing_stderr
|          |
|          +-stderr-> B_awk_writing_stdout_to_file_producing_stderr
|
+-stdout-> 3_cmd_producing_both_stdout_and_stderr
           |
           +-stdout-> C_awk_writing_stdout_to_file_producing_stderr
           |
           +-stderr-> D_awk_writing_stdout_to_file_producing_stderr
```

**Version 1:**
1 2 A B 3 C D

**Version 2:**
1 2 B A 3 D C

**Version 3:**
1 3 D C 2 B A

**Version 4:**
1 3 C D 2 A B

**NOTE:**

I tried
2 A B
and
2 B A, as well, they produce consistent outputs, similar to Version 1.

awk:
GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2-p3, GNU MP 6.0.0)

bash:
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

**Version 1**, this produces the output I expect:

```
( echo log; echo err 1>&2; ) \
    1> >( ( echo -n '1.'; cat; echo '1.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 1" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.out ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 2" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.err )
    ) \
    2> >( ( echo -n '2.'; cat; echo '2.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 3" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.out ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 4" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.err )
    )
```

files contents:

```
out.out 1.log
out.err 1.ERR
err.out 2.err
err.err 2.ERR
```

output:

```
error 4
error 2
error 1
error 3
```

**Version 2:**

NOTE: The 1st with the 2nd, the 3rd with the 4th second level indented lines are exchanged, compared to Version 1.

```
( echo log; echo err 1>&2; ) \
    1> >( ( echo -n '1.'; cat; echo '1.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 1" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.err ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 2" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.out )
    ) \
    2> >( ( echo -n '2.'; cat; echo '2.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 3" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.err ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 4" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.out )
    )
```

file contents:

```
(!) out.err error 2\n1.ERR
out.out 1.log
(!) err.err 2.ERR\nerror 4
err.out 2.err
```

output:

```
error 3
error 1
```

**Version 3:**

NOTE: The first level indented code-blocks are exchanged, compared to Version 2.

```
( echo log; echo err 1>&2; ) \
    2> >( ( echo -n '2.'; cat; echo '2.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 1" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.err ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 2" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.out )
    ) \
    1> >( ( echo -n '1.'; cat; echo '1.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 3" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.err ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 4" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.out )
    )
```

file contents:

```
(!) err.err error 2\n2.ERR
(!) err.out 2.err\nerror 3
(!) out.err 1.ERR\nerror 4
out.out 1.log
```

output:

```
error 1
(!)
```

**Version 4:**

NOTE: The 1st with the 2nd, the 3rd with the 4th second level indented lines are exchanged, compared to Version 3.

```
( echo log; echo err 1>&2; ) \
    2> >( ( echo -n '2.'; cat; echo '2.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 1" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.out ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 2" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.err )
    ) \
    1> >( ( echo -n '1.'; cat; echo '1.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 3" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.out ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 4" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.err )
    )
```

file contents:

```
(!) err.out 2.err\nerror 4\nerror 3
err.err 2.ERR
out.out 1.log
out.err 1.ERR
```

output:

```
error 2
error 1
(!)
```

What is happening in Version 2, 3, 4??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption that ordering of output redirection doesn't matter is incorrect.  Order matters a great deal.  Let's just consider the string "error 2" in code sample 2 and see why it gets written into the file `out.err`.  The code is:

```
( echo log; echo err 1>&2; ) \
    1> >( ( echo -n '1.'; cat; echo '1.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 1" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.err ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 2" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >out.out )
    ) \
    2> >( ( echo -n '2.'; cat; echo '2.ERR' 1>&2 ; ) \
        2> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 3" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.err ) \
        1> >( awk 'BEGIN { print "error 4" >"/dev/stderr" } { print $0 }' >err.out )
)
```

The string "error 2" is written by process B to its stderr.  Since the string that the shell parses to start process B does not contain a redirection to stderr, process B inherits its stderr from its parent.  Its parent is the subshell which you've labeled `2`.  That process has 2 redirections, each to subprocesses.  At the time process B is started, the stderr of process 2 has been directed to process A, so that is where process B will write the string.  Process A reads it and writes the string to its stdout, which is the file `out.err`.  If the reverse the order of the redirections, then the stderr of process `2` has not yet been redirected, so the stderr of process `B` would be the same as the stderr of the originating process (eg, your tty)

Comment: So, basically, You say that


1) process substitution redirections are evaluated in the same order as an _echo 3>&2 1>&2 2>file_ style redirection would be


2) new processes are created as the command line is evaluated, left to right, and each new command captures the actual redirection state (the open fd array) of the parent process. So in _echo 1> >(cmd1) 2> >(cmd2)_ cmd1 and cmd2 would get different sets of open fd-s? Like, I would need to do _echo 3>&1 1> >(cmd1) 2> >(cmd2 1>&3)_ so that cmd1 and cmd2 use the same, unaltered stderr and stdout?

Comment: Yes.  Indeed, `2> >(cmd)` is translated to `2>/dev/fdxx` and the device is created by the shell to handle the data.